# Adaptive Payment: How to close lightbox from close url?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have GWT application which is integrating with lightbox on AdaptivePayment API.

I am having trouble closing the cancel/return pages using the code provided:

```
dgFlow = top.dgFlow || top.opener.top.dgFlow; 
    dgFlow.closeFlow(); 
    top.close();
```

I tried calling above code from inside/outside of the Iframe containing cancel/return pages however
failed to dismiss the flow. Could someone give me an example of the use case?

Thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was calling:

```
 var dgFlow = new $wnd.PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow({ trigger: 'invokeOverlay' });
```

JSNI methods are decalred inside an IFrame, so dgFlow was never a global variable.

```
 $wnd.dgFlow = new $wnd.PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow({ trigger: 'invokeOverlay' });
```

Add the variable to the document Window to make it explicitly global.